Difference in delta of options with same parameters
Let's consider we have two hypothetical options with the same parameters under the Black Model (implied Vol, time to maturity etc.), the only difference being the value of the forward.
I am interested in the difference of delta between these two options. Instead of computing the delta of the two options and taking the difference, is there any equivalent where I could  compute the delta of another hypothetical option with same parameters than above but with a forward price equal to the difference of the forwards of my two hypothetical options and a specific strike?

At least to my knowledge I do not know of such a thing that exists. Because the delta difference is a different quantity as compared to delta of an option. Therefore using the delta difference as a delta for a special type of option doesn't really make sense.

If you are happy with a first order approximation, the difference between the delta of the options with different forwards is the gamma.
Let's call $c(x)$ the Black Scholes price when the forward is $x$, while all other values are fixed (including the strike, which you did not mention).
Then you have $\delta(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}c(x)$.
You are interested in the difference $\delta(x_1) - \delta(x_2)$.
Using the Taylor expansion, this is $\delta(x_1) - \delta(x_2) \sim (x_1-x_2) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}c(x) + o(x_1-x_2)^2$
The question at which point to compute the gamma is more theoretical than anything else. The best would be at the middle point $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$, but the average of the gammas is good too.
